# jQuery Mobile dialogs don't appear on AJAX requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have a dialog that appears on an "inner" page of a jQuery Mobile app (ie: a page you navigate to from the homepage). Navigation is done via AJAX, so a div with `data-role="page"` is loaded in and animated.

The problem is that, if I request the inner page via standard means, the dialog appears when I request it, via `$.mobile.changePage`, however when requested via AJAX the dialog doesn't appear at all.

It's in the correct place, as a sibling (not a child) of the `data-role="page"` element, and I've tried including it in various different places but it simply doesn't load appear when the page is requested via AJAX.

Any ideas? Here's the code that opens the dialog:

```
$('a[data-action="audio"]').on('click',
    function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.mobile.changePage('#recording',
            {
                transition: 'pop',
                changeHash: false,
                role: 'dialog'
            }
        );
    }
);
```

The `div[data-role="dialog"]` is part of the HTML file that gets loaded in via the AJAX request. I've also tried the mythical `dialog()` function which naturally does nothing :)

Any ideas?

Comment: requested via `$.ajax()` function?

Answer (score 1):

While i'm not 100% sure without seeing more code I believe your `.on` is not being bound correctly. I think your `.on` is currently bound to an element that changes/loaded with ajax.

Please test with this:

```
 $(body).on('click', 'a[data-action="audio"]',
```

If this works then you should change `body` to an element that isn't ajax'd in.